# Complex combination of AND / OR CLAUSES in MySql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute a complex combination of AND / OR clauses in MySql, but the result is not the one expected.

I think I've already tried all the possible combinations of brackets and I changed the clauses order about one hundred times, but nothing  worked correctly... So now I'm a little confused.

My table columns are the followings: ID, idfrom, idto, status.

This is one of my last attempts and the one that looks more logical to me (but maybe it's still far from the solution):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ( idfrom = '$user_id' AND
( status = 'success' OR status = 'estimation' )) OR
( idto = '$user_id' AND ( status = 'sent' OR status = 'confirmed' ... ) )
```

What I need is to get results in these cases:

1) if idfrom is equal to userid and status is set to 'success' or 'estimation'

2) if idto is equal to userid and status is set to 'sent' or 'confirmed'.

Is this a possible query or should I completely change the approach?

Comment: You can simplify with: `WHERE (idfrom = '$user_id' AND status IN ('success', 'estimation')) OR (idto = '$user_id' AND status IN ('sent', 'confirmed', ...))`, but otherwise I see no problem with your SQL assuming 1) and 2) are OR conditions.

Comment: is it working? what issue are you facing??

Comment: Of course, depending on where $user_id comes from (from a form submission?), you may be exposed to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: **HINT:** simply use `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (idfrom = '$user_id' OR idto = '$user_id')` and then i suggest you to use `PHP` for checking `status` as you already using `PHP` tag

Comment: I think now it was working using IN condition, but actually I think I will try checking status after the basic query as suggested by devpro. Thank you guys